# Simple query working in SQL but not in Sqlite3 in python

Tags: sqlite

Below is the sql query that is working fine:

```
SELECT * FROM contracts.wires.monthly_data
```

But it is not working in python

```
import sqlite3 
connection = sqlite3.connect("contractsdbro") 
print(connection) 
crsr = connection.cursor() 
crsr.execute("SELECT * FROM contracts.wires.monthly_data")
ans= crsr.fetchall()
```

**Error:**

```
 sqlite3.OperationalError: near ".": syntax error
```

Comment: change * to field names and you should be through

Comment: @Satya : Just tried that ( "SELECT transaction_id, ag_amount FROM contracts.wires.monthly_data" working fine in sql ) ; still getting the same error in python.

Comment: can you explain what is contracts , wires , monthly_data

Comment: @Satya: contracts.wires.monthly_data is working fine when I run in SQL, so I think it should be contract is SchemaName and wire is TableName , so not sure what is third component. (not really an sql expert)

Comment: @Satya : think contracts is the database, wires is the schemaname and monthly_data is the tablename

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in
[image]

the valid syntax is `schema-name.table-name` (you have an extra component).

You haven't provided enough information, but just guessing

```
crsr.execute("SELECT * FROM monthly_data")
```

should work.

You can use `sqlite3` command-line tool to explore your database.

Comment: You might want to also include the corrected code to make this a complete answer.

Comment: @Diego : contracts.wires.monthly_data is working fine in SQL , so can you tell what is its equivalent in slqite3 ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen : think contracts is the database, wires is the schemaname and monthly_data is the tablename

Comment: @AnandKC - there's no schema names in SQLite unless you attach databases. If you're not attaching databases and only have one database you don't need anything other than `select * from monthly_data`.

Comment: @GIS-Jonathan : Thanks, I have multiple databases , in that case what should be my command

Comment: @AnandKC - whatever the schema is as Diego's answer says. So if you attach it with a schema of 'accounts' then it'd be `select * from accounts.monthly_data`

Comment: @AnandKC as you don't have any `attach` in your example, it should be only table (i.e. `montly_data`)

Comment: @GIS-Jonathan  :  so `crsr.execute("SELECT * FROM monthly_data")` , is giving me error: **sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: monthly_data**. 
Also , contractsdbro = server name, wires = schemaname and monthly_data = tablename

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano